# QGraphicsProxyWidget::setPos(qreal x, qreal y) doesn't place correctly in a QGraphicsScene when coordinates > 2^15

Tags: qt, position, qgraphicsscene

I have a `QGraphicsScene` of big dimension for displaying a database content.

Part of the database is made of pictures that I place in the `QGraphicsScene` thanks to the method `setPos()` of a `QGraphicsPixmapItem` and this works fine with thousands of pictures.

In front of these pictures, I place `QCheckbox`es that are finally accessible through `QGraphicsProxyWidget`s. But `QGraphicsProxyWidget::setPos(qreal x, qreal y)` results in casting provided coordinates in signed short in the `QGraphicsScene`.
However, doing a `QGraphicsProxyWidget::pos()` returns correctly the original coordinates, even above 2^16.

Here is the code:

```
QCheckBox* checkbox = new QCheckBox("", this);

QWidget* dummyWidget = new QWidget; //used for having a transparent background
dummyWidget->setStyleSheet("background-color:transparent;"
                           "outline-color:transparent;"
                           "font-size: 8pt;");

QHBoxLayout* dummyLayout = new QHBoxLayout(dummyWidget);
dummyLayout->addWidget(checkbox);

QGraphicsProxyWidget* proxyWidget = scene.addWidget(dummyWidget);
proxyWidget->setPos(0, 120*i);
```

When 120*i is between 32769 and 65536, `QChekBox`es don't show. For above values, `QCheckBox`es are shown like if `y = value - 65536`.

I have tried many things without success, like
- `proxyWidget->moveBy`
- `dummyWidget->move`
- `dummyWidget->setFixedSize(0, 240*i); checkbox->move(0, 120*i);`

Any solution?

PS: The toolchain/cross-toolchain I depend from embeds QT4.8.1. for the desktop side.
I have no way to change that so upgrading to QT5.x is not an option.

Comment: Just curious, why do you need to use such large coordinates?

Comment: You can give a look to Adobe's Lightroom for instance to see the kind of application that would need such large scene, here at the bottom of the GUI for displaying the pictures.  And because for applications graphic style imports as well, so when you have the right design for it...

Comment: But it is absolutely no need to create that large scene, because you never can display it in full size having no such a large display. What I propose, is just "simulate" the large coordinates, instead of physically create such a large scenes.

Comment: Well, I thought about such principle before starting coding but I couldn't set in my mind an efficient way to do it without having to recompute several things for the display, thus meaning latency issue.  The current solution allows me to switch quickly between the content of several huge databases once the scene has been processed for each of them. If I was supposed to have a problem, it should have been displaying the QGraphicsPixmapItems, not just simple checkboxes that are the cherry on the cake. QGraphicsPixmapItems display works like a charm but not the QCheckBox display :-s

Comment: What size has the `scene`? Did you set the `scene` size?

Answer (score 0):

You can use next trick:

```
void setNewPos(QGraphicsItem *item, QPointF pos)
{
    item->resetTransform();
    QTransform trans = item->transform();
    item->setTransform(trans.translate(pos.x(), pos.y()));
}
```

Now, you can call this func:

```
QPushButton *btn = new QPushButton("Hello, people!");
QGraphicsProxyWidget *wdgItem = scene->addWidget(btn);
setNewPos(wdgItem, view->mapToScene(0,0)); // There's scenePos can have any coords
```